# How do I convert Emgu::CV::Mat to OpenCV cv::Mat and vice versa?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, c++-cli, emgucv

I have to use OpenCV in both managed and unmanaged code in C++/CLI.

I'm trying Emgu CV in the managed code to wrap around the OpenCV objects but I'm having trouble doing the conversions.

How do I do something like this:

```
Emgu::CV::Mat convert = Function_That_Returns_OpenCV_CV_Mat();
```

or this:

```
Function_That_Takes_OpenCV_CV_Mat(Emgu_CV_Mat_variable);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OpenCV Mat to Emgu Mat:

```
cv::Mat openCvMat = Function_That_Returns_OpenCV_CV_Mat();
System::IntPtr openCvMatSystemIntPtr = openCvMat.ptr;
Emgu::CV::Mat^ result = 
   Emgu::CV::CvInvoke::CvArrToMat(
      openCvMatSystemIntPtr, false, false, 0);
```

Comment: What about the other direction?

Comment: This seems somewhat unsafe to me. At this point, wouldn't both the openCvMat and result claim ownership over the pointer (as you're not copying the memory as you specify false to that argument) and one or the other could easily be disposed of before the other?